# List articles by Category and Sub-Category

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, overrides, subcategories

It seems unbelievably difficult to display a list of articles, grouped by their category/subcategory with the category as a sub-heading.

The Articles Category module seems to come close as I can choose to group the articles by Category but it would be really cool if I could show the group title, ie. the Category, as a heading for each group.

Any ideas how I might be able to do this by customising the default.php module layout?  Or any other way to achieve a nice neat list of articles with category subheadings?

Comment: Categories as headings? You mean you want to choose multiple categories for a single menu item and show their articles with a heading title for each category? Or select a single category and show articles grouped by subcategories. Can you visualize somehow what you want to do with a diagram, mentioning your categories structure and how they should appear ?

Answer (score 5):

Option 1: Create a menu for your categories and articles. Everytime you add an article to your category, you also add it to your menu. Then you use the menu module to call in that information. It'll be a menu, but it'll look like categories and articles.

Option 2: Create multiple modules, one for each category, and call them all into that space. They'll tile on top of each other, pull the relevant articles, and look as though they are one unit, even though they are several.

Option 3: Hit the Joomla Extension Directory for other article and category displaying modules and see what you find. I like Display News, but I'm not sure off the top of my head that it'll do exactly what you're looking for.

Option4: This just occurred to me. It's a little crazy, and it's more or less used to organize option 2 and make it a little more dynamic. Using Article Categories, instead of Article Category, you call the category list into your website. Make sure you ALSO call the category descriptions. Then in the description of each category, you call a module for that category that lists its articles.  Now it really is one unit, but it's pulling pieces from your modules, articles and categories.

Whatever you do, make sure you have a top level menu item for your category blog, to ensure your articles take the styles you want.

Comment: Your Option 4 is ingenious! And seems to work, too.  It means creating a lot of modules (I have a lot of categories) and a bit of fiddling around with the formatting but I think I'll be able to make something that works well.  Many thanks for your help and ideas.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I just did something like this to call an icon to represent the categories in DisplayNews, as well as Article Categories, so I can't believe I didn't think of it right away. I'm all about finding crazy ways to make things happen. :D